# Module not Found error. Keeps coming up even though they are already installed

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, modulenotfounderror, pandas-datareader

I have been working on a code to transfer stock data to an excel spreadsheet [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW8Zh.png). The code works while in spyder but when I run it in CMD I get the following error message about my libraries.[Error message even though clearly installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgTv.png). I have everything installed in my IDE and CMD.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but other than that I am completely lost. New to coding.

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. pip installed the module for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Type `pip install pandas` to install pandas module but please before installing dependencies make sure you create virtual environment for your project. So it won't contradict later on. You can use conda, virtualenv wrapper and many things as virtual environement.